# Print every 3rd multiple page on a new sheet/paper

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, printer, default-settings

I have around 100 pages in a pdf file. I have to print them in such a way that every 3rd multiple has to be printed on single paper and rest all in both sides.

e.g. If we consider my file is of 9 pages. then it has to print on the following order:

Paper 1: Pages 1 and 2 should print on both sides of the paper.

Paper 2: Page 3 alone should print

Paper 3: Pages 4 and 5 should print on both sides of the paper.

Paper 4: page 6 alone should print.

Paper 5: Page 7 and 8 should print on both sides of the paper.

Paper 6: Page 9 alone should print.

Can someone please help me how to print them in a single shot? What should be printer settings to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a simple printer setting. It might be better to insert a blank page every 4th page, starting on the 3rd. (so page, page, page, blank, repeat) It is a question how the PDF is made, if a new version of the PDF can be delivered to you with those pages inserted by default. Otherwise, you can use software to modify a pdf and insert blank pages.

Comment: @LPChip I second that. There is no driver or software that will do the job. The only way is to insert blank pages in the PDF and then print the whole thing double-sided. PDFTKBuilder (free) can insert the pages, but there may be easier ways.